# Run process of Client computer from WinForm application hosted on Citrix

Tags: winforms, citrix

I have a winform application which needs to open a CSV file stored on client's PC. I am using the following code to open the CSV file and it works locally.

```
Process.Start(CSVPath);
```

However, the code does not work when I run the winform application from Citrix. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you aware that software running on Citrix is not running on the PC but on a server? However, you will need to access a virtual drive or network drive...

Comment: Where is the CSV path pointing to? Have you tried Environment.GetFolderPath()?